# Test GMail marketplace app flow

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

So here I am again, exploring new Google platform and hunting down information and docs.

I'm trying to build a skeleton of a flow before I write any business logic code with actual use of the APIs, and as expected from Google, this process is excruciatingly painful.

I've tried to follow this doc:
https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/listing

Packaged the zip, put the flag *DOMAIN_INSTALLABLE* flag as was instructed in order for the app to be installible from the marketplace. In the dashboard of PRICING & DISTRIBUTION I've selected Private and added testers to the list of testers.

Now when I click *View in Chrome Web Store* (seen in image) it takes me to the **extensions** web store, and not to the marketplace store.
[image]

How can I get to the GSuite Marketplace flow, rather than the extension flow? Do I need to alter my *manifest.json* in some way that is not mentioned in the docs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it's true that the publishing flow is too complicated now. We are working on improvements and in the future everything will be in one place.

Unfortunately G Suite Marketplace does not support trusted testers (yet), that's why it doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

What you might be able to do, is modify the url a bit after you clicked on 'View in Chrome Web Store'.
Just remove everything after the webstore id

I use this url:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xxxxxx

xxxx should be your webstore id

You should be able to show your unlisted app in the Gsuite Marketplace, where you can initiate the install flow.

It works for me, but my test app